# Bound checks for array and string slices

Tags: f#

I can't seem to get my head around the rules that govern these two cases:
1. The end index may be one less than the start index, producing an empty array/string.
2. It's apparently legal to position the start index just behind the last element, if the end index is one less, as before.

```
[|0..2|].[3..2];;    // [||]
"bar".[3..2];;       // ""
```

A naive implementation of bound checks with consideration of case 1 wouldn't allow case 2:

```
let trySlice i j (a : string) =
    let lastIdx = a.Length - 1
    if i < 0 || i > lastIdx || j < i - 1 || j > lastIdx then None
    else Some a.[i..j]

trySlice 3 2 "bar"  // None
```

What's the rationale behind this behavior? How to proceed?

**Edit**
This is what I have now thanks to Tarmil's input

```
let trySlice i j (a : string) =
    if i >= 0 && j >= i - 1 && j < a.Length then Some a.[i..j]
    else None
```

which should be equivalent to

```
let trySlice' i j (s : string) =
    try s.Substring(i, j - i + 1) |> Some
    with _ -> None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the rationale is that `a.[i..j]` is a sequence of length `(j - i + 1)`, so in a way it makes sense to allow `i = j + 1` as a way to extract an empty sequence.

As for "how to proceed", if you want your `trySlice` to accept all cases that the built-in slicing accepts, then just remove the `i > lastIdx` clause. When `i = lastIdx + 1`, the only way for the other conditions to pass is if `j = lastIdx`, and when `i > lastIdx + 1`, there is no way for `j` to pass both its constraints.

As a side-note, the way you write:

```
if (failCondition || failCondition || ...) then None else Some x
```

feels counter-intuitive to me for some reason, I would have written it as:

```
if (successCondition && successCondition && ...) then Some x else None
```

Comment: Thank you. I found it hard to reason about this and couldn't see for my life that the second condition was redundant, except for case 2.  Ad

Comment: As for the fail-conditions being more intuitively placed between the logical _and_, that doesn't apply neither to pattern-matching (where `|` is much more often used than `&`) nor to multiple argument check statements of the form `if condition then raise <| exn()`